# Adding new filetypes to Windows 7's New context menu

Tags: windows, windows-7

I'm trying to add CSS, PHP, JS and HTML file types to the "New" right click menu in Windows 7. I know how to add the file types to the menu with ShellNew entries in the registry. But Windows doesn't give you any control over the display names of the new items - according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#new) the name's always taken from whatever application you've assigned to open the doc. I've set Notepad++ to open all of these file types, so I'm going to end up with several identical "Notepad++ document" entries in the menu, like this:

[image: Windows Explorer context menu]

Does anybody know if there's a way out of this stupid situation without installing any tweak utilities?

Thanks all!
Fred

Comment: I'd love to know how to do this too...

Answer (score 3):

To rename a context menu > new's item (in Windows 7, at least):

1. Open regedit.
2. Go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.%ext%` and note the `(Default)` value. This is the file extension's ProdID.
3. Go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\%ProdID%` (usually `%ext%file`) using the value obtained from step two. Set the `(Default)` value to whatever you would like the context menu new item to display as.
4. Under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\%ProdID%`, if there is a `FriendlyTypeName` value, rename it to `FriendlyTypeName.old`, as the `(Default)` value "[is deprecated by the FriendlyTypeName entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/cc144152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)"

I don't believe there is even a need to log out / restart, but if the changes don't take effect, log out and/or restart.

Comment: Thanks Ben, this is the same as the solution suggested by Anders, which didn't do the trick for me. Basically I have 3 filetypes I want to create a "new file" menu items for, .js, .css, .htm, all in Notepad++. This means that for each of those extensions the default value is "Notepad++_file". If I set the Default value for Notepad++_file to "CSS file", that becomes the text for the new .js and .htm menu items as well.

Comment: Yes, I noticed they were similar but @Anders' solution didn't work for me because of, as I found out later, the `FriendlyTypeName` issue. So, I thought I'd post it as an answer.

How did you associate the files with Notepad++?

Comment: Oh I see, sorry, missed that. I just associated the filetypes in the standard Win Explorer options.

Answer (score 2):

You could change the file type description for each file class manually.

1. Look up the prog id under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.%ext%` (The default value)
2. Under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\%progid%`, set the default value and/or the "FriendlyTypeName" string to the string you want.

You might have to log off for it to take effect.
You should probably stay away from the Chrome and Notepad++ file type/association dialogs so they don't overwrite your strings.

Both Chrome and Notepad++ are open source, you can create a patch for them that use better names for the file types. (What is a "Chrome HTML Document" anyway, HTML5 + extra chrome juice? =) )

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Anders - unfortunately neither of these has worked for me - changed first one value and logged out and in again, then the other. Bah!

Answer (score -1):

I was able to derive a solution from the answers above.

1. I replicated the particular application (JetBrains PHPStorm in my case) registry entry.

   > PHPStorm2019.1 -> PHPStorm2019.1.scss, PHPStorm2019.1.js.
2. Now I changed the Default REG_SZ of `PHPStorm2019.1.scss` to **SCSS File** and `PHPStorm2019.1.js` to **JavaScript file**.
3. Mapped `.scss` and `.js` to `PHPStorm2019.1.scss` and `PHPStorm2019.1.js` respectively.

[image]